API Gateway POST Request is not getting request body
I have an ECS Fargate task written in Java. Within, I'm trying to make a POST request to an API Gateway endpoint.
API Gateway logs show me that it is receiving the request but it shows an empty request body:
(acaf3df0-1ac1-4964-b4f7-f51943e8f59a) Method request body before transformations: 
...
(acaf3df0-1ac1-4964-b4f7-f51943e8f59a) Endpoint request body after transformations: 
...
(acaf3df0-1ac1-4964-b4f7-f51943e8f59a) Endpoint response body before transformations: {
    "message": "2 validation errors detected: Value null at 'dataType' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must not be null; Value null at 'dataMetric' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must not be null"

This is how I'm making the request, passing the request body into the .contentStreamProvider:
...
SdkHttpFullRequest request = SdkHttpFullRequest.builder()
    .uri(uri)
    .method(SdkHttpMethod.POST)
    .putHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
    .contentStreamProvider(() -> SdkBytes.fromString(requestBody, StandardCharsets.UTF_8).asInputStream())
.build();
...


It's a bit unclear where the error is.  You're passing off the payload but if you're not getting the correct thing back then you'd need to check on the server side to see what's wrong.

I'm not sure how ECS is even relevant here. This code wouldn't be any different running anywhere else. What happens when you run this locally?
